# How to remove model using command line from CakePHP project

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2, cakephp-model

I have an annoying model that I accidentally created that keeps interfering with my `cake schema run update` command. how can I destroy this model?

ok, I believe it is just easier to remove model file. I was just curious about cakephp-scripts implementation but it's not really necessary.

Comment: Check the models directory and remove it from there.

Comment: way to do it in command line?

Comment: "rm *" isn't a command in the command line? :-p :-D

Comment: oh yes of course. i shoudl have been more clear, i meant the cake console..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be located in

```
/install-dir
    /app
        /models
            model.php
```

For comment:

I know Unix.

```
cd /path/to/your/install-dir/app/models
rm model.php
```

Obviously you would replace that path with whatever is valid for your install.  Depending on your permissions you may need to `sudo rm` that as well.

Also: http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/

Answer (score 1):

[From command line](http://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm):
`DEL C:\path-to-your-project\app\models\hated-model.php`